# What word can be used for work done after some event (i.e. the opposite of preparation)?

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say there is some work event in an office work/IT setting, e.g. a meeting/workshop/brainstorm session/you-name-it. Some tasks are done in advance to prepare for this event - i.e. they are done *in preparation* of this event/meeting.

Then, after the actual event happens there are some more tasks to be done - e.g. documentation/organizational tasks/communication/...

What word could be used to describe these sort of tasks, performed *after the fact*?

- *Cleanup* doesn't quite fit the bill because it is rather misleading on what is actually done.
- *Debrief* fits rather well, but there is only one person involved - i.e. there is no-one to actually debrief...

Comment: You aren't defining a particular context. With cooking, *cleanup* fits perfectly. With agents in the field, *debrief* fits perfectly. What you list under *e.g.* is fine, but very broad. Any number of things could be included in that list (which you leave open with the ellipsis)—including things that make either *cleanup* or *debrief* appropriate. So, you'll need to be more precise.

Comment: @JasonBassford I tried to make the context more explicit. Is it sufficient?

Comment: For a situation involving scaffolding, tables, etc, "knockdown" is sometimes used.

Comment: @fgysin No, because either *cleanup* or *debrief* could be used, depending on what you're trying to express about what happens after the meeting.

Comment: @fgysin Are you perhaps thinking of *follow-up*? Things that are done as a result of decisions made during the meeting—rather than actions involved in the so-called undoing of the preparations?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

“Post hoc” is something done after the fact.

I’d be comfortable using the phrases “post hoc documentation”, “post hoc organizational tasks” and “post hoc communication”.

“Action items” might also work.

Answer (score -1):

Generally in IT, we call them *takeaways*, for tasks to be performed after the meeting/event, such as setup the next meeting.  Usually this is a list of assignments to particular people.

Also see https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11848/what-does-take-away-mean-in-this-context

Comment: I don't recall "takeaway" being used in this sense in 45 years in the computer biz.