# Opposite of preparation / is there a word for winding down after an event?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, antonyms

#### Idea

I am wondering, if I **prepare** before an event by getting into my running clothes and we call this "preparation".
Is there a word for then getting out of my running clothes *after the event*?

#### Elaboration

Trying to elaborate on my thoughts, consider this:

| Preparation | What I am looking for |
| --- | --- |
| Prepare | Postpare (?) |

##### Example

Another example:

- I would say I *prepare* for some event by **driving** there (when talking about tasks).
- What do I say for driving back home if I also consider this a task I need to complete?

##### Related question

There seems to be someone who had a similar thought, [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/472880/290741).
However, this question has a completely different focus / discusses IT specifically and the answer do not answer my question at all.

Comment: *Decompressing* is what people do when they travel home from a day's work.

Comment: *Recovery* or *cooldown* (opposite of warm-up) are terms often used in exercise and fitness. There are also terms like *debriefing* (which has extended beyond the original meaning). I guess it depends if the focus to recover energies, to relax/calm down, to repair/tidy/put away, to reflect on how it went, to prepare for next time, etc.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Please provide answers in the answer box, not the comment box.

Comment: @StuartF Please provide answers in the answer box, not the comment box.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127217/discussion-on-question-by-creativecreatorormaybenot-opposite-of-preparation-is).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To [**conclude**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conclude) (i.e., to bring to a close, especially through an action) or to [**wrap up**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wrap%20up) (i.e., to bring to a successful conclusion) or to [**complete**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complete) (i.e., to bring to a final state) could all sound natural in this context.

> *I like to prepare for a run by stretching and a glass of water, and I like to **wrap it up** with more stretching and an herbal tea.*

> *With a ride home from a friend and upon storing my gear, my hiking day trip was **completed**.*

> *I **concluded** my exercise session by getting out of my sweaty clothes, showering, and putting on my favorite robe.*

For further separation from the activity, as requested in the comments, please consider **restore**, **reset**, **recover**, or **rehome**. Just as “prepare” involves necessarily changing  one’s state, conditions, or arrangements for on upcoming event, these terms capture the necessary actions to return to the default condition.

Comment: I really like these :) One note, however, I would say that these are all still part of the activity because it is about bringing the activity to an end. While preparing on the other hand happens **before** the activity.

Comment: Thank you! I don't agree, though, that the act of running includes a subsequent beverage, that the act of hiking necessarily includes putting away the equipment, that the act of exercising includes putting on a robe. The subsequent actions are all independent aspects that the speaker chooses to follow the key activity, just as they chose to prepare for the key activity with certain preceding aspects.

Comment: I agree 100% with your comment. What I was trying to say is that the **words** "conclude", "wrap up", and "complete" are all still part of the activity. Concluding e.g. might be closing a meeting.

Comment: I added another couple sentences to my answer to wrap it up. Now I'll recenter and recalibrate for the next question.

Answer (score 5):

To me this is one of those questions where the question already contains the best answer. The term 'winding down' is actually used by many people to mean just what you are looking for. I have no sources to back up this contention and would have posted it as a comment had comments not been blocked.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I chose "winding down" as I thought it was the best fit I know of. However, it did not feel like the precise word I was looking for. I was hoping something like "postpare" **actually** exists - it appears not. Maybe establishing "postpare" would be useful because it is more precise :) But then again, I am not sure about the etymology of prepare, so it might be a bad idea.

Comment: 'Wind-down' is given by Macmillan and applies better to the overall fait accompli than to the actual sitting down / packing away / driving back details (for which the ing-form is a better fit).

Comment: +1 "Winding down" is an excellent complement to colloquial preparation-related phrases such as "gearing/ramping/revving/suiting/spinning up."

Answer (score 0):

### postpare /poʊstˈpɛr/

This is not a word in the English language as of today. However, I do think that **postpare** is incredibly precise, compared to the other suggestions posted here.
I would argue that *postpare* is also self-explanatory, assuming readers are familiar with the "pre-"/"post-" pattern, i.e. the meaning of these words.

---

That is why I want to try to establish *postpare* as the opposite of *prepare*. This can be extended to "preparation" vs. "postparation", i.e. to the noun and also to the adjective, "prepared" vs "postpared".
Maybe some other people will catch onto it :)

Comment: Inventing non-standard forms ia expressly off-topic on ELU.